# How to create a search result page with multiple queries

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.6

I have a table called Properties and there I store the price,city,bathrooms,bedrooms and suburb.

So I know I want to perform search based on those fields.

If I search by suburb only, it works, if I search property type it also works, but when trying to select min_price or/and max_price, bathrooms and bedrooms, I don't get the desired result.

My controller looks like this:

```php
public function search_page(Request $request)
{
    // validation ...
    $query = Property::query();

    if ($city = $request->input('city') ?? '')
    {
        $query->where('city', $city)
    ->orWhere('suburb', $city);
    }

    if ($type = $request->input('type') ?? '')
    {
        $query->where('type', $type);
    }

    // if none of them is null
    if (! (is_null($request->input('min_price')) && is_null($request->input('max_price')))) {
        // fetch all between min & max values
        $query->whereBetween('price', [$request->input('min_price'), $request->input('max_price')]);
    }
    // if just min_price is available (is not null)
    elseif (! is_null($request->input('min_price'))) {
        // fetch all greater than or equal to min_price
        $query->where('price', '>=', $request->input('min_price'));
    }
    // if just max_value is available (is not null)
    elseif (! is_null($request->input('max_price'))) {
        // fetch all lesser than or equal to max_value
        $query->where('price', '<=', $request->input('max_price'));
    }

    $properties = $query->orderBy('id', 'asc')->paginate(9);

    return view('pages.search', compact('properties'));     
}
```

And below are the search inputs:

```php
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'GET', 'action'=>'AdminPropertyController@search_page']) !!}
    <div class="row flex wrap">

        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="search-input">
                {!! Form::text('city', null, ['class'=>'form-controla', 'placeholder'=>'Search for area,city, or suburb']) !!}          
            </div>

            <div class="select-boxes">
                {!! Form::select('type', [''=>'Type of property'] + ['apartment'=>'Apartment', 'house'=>'House', 'plot'=>'Plot', 'smallholding'=>'Smallholding', 'commercial'=>'Commercial', 'townhouse'=>'Townhouse'], null, ['class'=>'form-']) !!}               
                {!! Form::select('min_price', [''=>'Minimum'] + [1=>'1', 20=>'20'], null, ['class'=>'form-']) !!}                       
                {!! Form::select('maxprice', [''=>'Maximum'] + [1=>'1', 20=>'20'], null, ['class'=>'form-']) !!}
                {!! Form::select('bedrooms', [''=>'Bedroom'] + [2=>'1+', 3=>'2+'], null, ['class'=>'form-']) !!}
                {!! Form::select('bathrooms', [''=>'bathroom'] + [2=>'1+', 3=>'2+'], null, ['class'=>'form-']) !!}
            </div>                                              
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-2">
            {!! Form::submit('Search', ['class'=>'search bg-brown']) !!}
            <button class="clear-filter button">Clear Filter</button>
        </div>                  
    </div>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

How can I make my search work properly?

Comment: What does "I don't get the desired result" mean? Please provide a http://sqlfiddle.com with some sample data and the expected vs. actual result.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is here:

```
// if none of them is null
if (! (is_null($request->input('min_price')) && is_null($request->input('max_price')))) {
    // fetch all between min & max values
    $query->whereBetween('price', [$request->input('min_price'), $request->input('max_price')]);
}
// if just min_price is available (is not null)
elseif (! is_null($request->input('min_price'))) {
    // fetch all greater than or equal to min_price
    $query->where('price', '>=', $request->input('min_price'));
}
// if just max_value is available (is not null)
elseif (! is_null($request->input('max_price'))) {
    // fetch all lesser than or equal to max_value
    $query->where('price', '<=', $request->input('max_price'));
}
```

At the beginning you use condition:

```
if (! (is_null($request->input('min_price')) && is_null($request->input('max_price')))) {
```

So when in request there is min_price but there is no max_price, it will be true because: `!(false && true)` gives `!false` and it gives `true`. Probably this is the reason why you get unexpected result.

Instead of the above line you should rather use:

```
if (!is_null($request->input('min_price')) && !is_null($request->input('max_price'))) {
```

Now, when in request there is min_price but there is no max_price you will have `(!false && !true)` what gives `(true && false)` and it give `false`.